# How can I set the .hidden property of an object of another view on a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, sdk, tabs

Dear all - I have a Tab Based Application (started as the XCode Example app).

One tab is used to pick an image (UIImagePickerController) - works as intended.
Another tab is used to display CoreGraphics over a UIImageView containing the image chosen.  This is done in the drawRect: Method of a custom UIView.

I need to reset the interface on the UIView when a new image is selected.

At present I have a `-(IBAction)resetAll:(id)sender` method in my UIView - when this is called from a button on the same view everything resets as intended.

HOWEVER, when I call the resetAll method from the viewWillAppear method of the ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];    

TabBarEgAppAppDelegate *delegate = (TabBarEgAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


if(delegate.newphotopicked){

[myView resetAll:nil];

delegate.newphotopicked = NO;

}
```

The NSLog in the resetAll method is triggered but the parameters (such as `button.hidden = YES;`) do not get set.

Is this because the UIView is hidden in some way by the TabBarViewController?  How else can I reset my view when the tab changes (UIView doesn't call viewWillAppear does it?).  Thank you so much for giving me your time!

M@

Just to clarify, the ViewController has the following in the .h:

```
MyView *myView;
```

in the .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

The `[myView resetAll:nil];` call has the same effect from buttons and calls anywhere in the app INCLUDING on the UIView (MyView) itself.

I know now that I have linked up or subclassed badly (please help).

M@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this only happen the very first time the view tab is shown, or every time?  It's possible that the outlet objects have not yet been created and so are nil.   You can verify this in the debugger where your NSLog call is.   If that is true, then if you move your resetAll function to `viewDidAppear` then everything should work.

Comment: Hi Bogatyr, thanks for the help.  It happens every time I call the function from the ViewController. The Outlet objects are there I think - no errors in the console to suggest otherwise and same behaviour even if the methods are first called from the working button.  Do you mean to move the call to the viewDiDAppear method rather than viewWillAppear (this has the exact same behaviour for me) or do you mean to define the function in the ViewController?  If I define it in the view controller (sorry to ask a stupid question here) how to I set the properties on the view?

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting moving the call to DID from WILL, with the idea that everything should be created by then and non-nil.   Both of these methods are in the UIViewController class, and you can implement them or not according to your needs.     view properties are set by "self.view.property = value", because UIViewController has its view as the property named "view".   Did everything work out?   I just noticed you accepted...